# floating-ui arrow and scroll issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, floating-ui

I want to build a popover for my RichText editor so that when I select a piece of text, a popover appears with some buttons like bold, italic etc. It should change it's position automatically when more/less text is selected. My current problems are:

- popover flips its position only when scrolling the main scrollbar from body tag, not the one that comes from the container with my editor. When I scroll inside the editor container, the tooltip does not change it positions to match the position of a selected text which changes due to scrolling
- I tried to add an arrow but it positioning is wrong (too far from the `floating` element and don't flip as well when popover flips

Here is the relevant code. Do you have any suggestions how to fix above issues?

```js
export const ControlledBubbleMenu = ({ editor, open, children }: Props) => {
  const arrowRef = useRef(null);
  const {
    x,
    y,
    strategy,
    floatingStyles,
    refs: { reference, setReference, setFloating },
    middlewareData,
    context,
  } = useFloating({
    strategy: 'fixed',
    whileElementsMounted: autoUpdate,
    placement: 'bottom',
    middleware: [
      offset({ mainAxis: 8 }),
      flip({
        // padding: 8,
        boundary: editor.options.element,
        fallbackPlacements: [
          'top',
          'top-start',
          'bottom-start',
          'top-end',
          'bottom-end',
        ],
      }),
      //   shift(),
      arrow({
        element: arrowRef,
      }),
    ],
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setReference({
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        const { ranges } = editor.state.selection;
        const from = Math.min(...ranges.map((range) => range.$from.pos));
        const to = Math.max(...ranges.map((range) => range.$to.pos));

        if (isNodeSelection(editor.state.selection)) {
          const node = editor.view.nodeDOM(from) as HTMLElement;

          if (node) {
            return node.getBoundingClientRect();
          }
        }

        return posToDOMRect(editor.view, from, to);
      },
    });
  }, [reference, editor.state.selection]);

  if (!open) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <FloatingFocusManager context={context} modal={false}>
      <div className='bg-card' ref={setFloating} style={floatingStyles}>
        {children}
        <div
          ref={arrowRef}
          className='absolute h-[8px] w-[8px] rotate-45 bg-card'
          style={{
            left: middlewareData.arrow?.x,
            top: middlewareData.arrow?.y,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </FloatingFocusManager>
  );
};
```